# How to show content (<div>) as per selection options (<select>)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show content based on user's selection from `<select> <option>`.

Like, when user selects the `<option value="Option A">` then only show the `<div>` containing "Orange".

HTML:
`

```
 <div id="main-container">
        <select name="" id="user-selector" class="selector-dropdown">
            <option selected="true" style='display: none'>Select</option>
            <option value="Option A">Fruit</option>
            <option value="Option B">Animal</option>
            <option value="Option C">Language</option>
            <option value="Option C">Stationary</option>
        </select>

        <div class="output">Orange</div>
        <div class="output">Lion</div>
        <div class="output">English</div>
        <div class="output">Pen</div>

    </div>
```

`

I have searched in codepen, stackoverflow, and most were using jQuery which i couldn't understand.

It's been 2 days I've started learning JS. It really helps if you can help me the JS code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What you will need to do is create an event listener for the select that listens for its change.

I created a class called active that will show the div. By default I have css style for output that sets it as display none.

Then in the event listener, the first thing I do is remove the active class if it exists.

Also I add the value of the options as data attributes to the divs. This allows you to reference that div.

Then simply add the new active class to that div.

```js
let selector = document.querySelector(".selector-dropdown");

selector.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  let active = document.querySelector(".output.active");
  if (active) active.classList.remove("active");

  let _target = document.querySelector("[data-option='" + e.target.value + "']")

  if (_target) _target.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
.output {
  display: none;
}

.output.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <select name="" id="user-selector" class="selector-dropdown">
    <option selected="true" style='display: none'>Select</option>
    <option value="Option A">Fruit</option>
    <option value="Option B">Animal</option>
    <option value="Option C">Language</option>
    <option value="Option D">Stationary</option>
  </select>

  <div data-option="Option A" class="output">Orange</div>
  <div data-option="Option B" class="output">Lion</div>
  <div data-option="Option C" class="output">English</div>
  <div data-option="Option D" class="output">Pen</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Remember. A really simple rule of thumbs. Don't use Event.target unless you really understand what it actually returns. Use Event.currentTarget instead. Or in the other rare cases: Event.target.closest(). Also `const` is your friend, don't avoid it.